# Configure Visual Studio Code to share same terminal history from zsh?

Tags: zsh, visual-studio-code, command-history

I use both the built-in terminal of VScode + terminal (zsh) on Mac. I'm under the impression they used to share the same history but not anymore.

Ideally a command I type in either would be automatically appended to my usual history file at `/Users/<my-user>/.zsh_history`.

Is there a simple way to configure my vscode terminal to share the same history from my zsh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [bug in VSCode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168396) and should be fixed in the next release.

Until then the workaround is to add this line to your `~/.zshrc` :

```
HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
```

Comment: There is also [this option](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168396#issuecomment-1346874996) to set it on the user/workspace settings - Use `⌘+Shift+p` and type `Settings JSON` to access and then add this
`"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {"HISTFILE": "$HOME/.zsh_history"}`